# How to remove hyphenation without breaking into margin nor increasing space between words?

Tags: hyphenation, sloppy

To remove hyphenation, I used

```
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
```

Then the text broke into the margin area, so I did

```
\sloppy
```

Now the problem is Latex increased the space between words to fill up the line.
What I want instead is maintaing the space size the same as before, but just leave a large space at the end of that line. How do I do this?
Thank you.

Comment: `\raggedright`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

The declaration `\raggedright` or the environment form `\begin{flushleft}...\end{flushleft}` set text with uneven space at the right margin. As this space will be used in preference to hyphenation you will only get words hyphenated if they are wider than the text block.